# htaccess redirect not working for long url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect the following long link:

http://www.vbpmonitor.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=24&utm_source=MagnetMail&utm_medium=email&utm_term=asmith@panaceainc.com&utm_content=EVVWP040716&utm_campaign=White%20Paper%3A%20Optimizing%20VBM%20Quality%20Tiering%20for%20Physicians

to

http://www.vbpmonitor.com/optimizing-vbm-quality-tiering-for-physicians

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=24&utm_source=MagnetMail&utm_medium=email&utm_term=asmith@panaceainc.com&utm_content=EVVWP040716&utm_campaign=White%20Paper%3A%20Optimizing%20VBM%20Quality%20Tiering%20for%20Physicians http://www.vbpmonitor.com/optimizing-vbm-quality-tiering-for-physicians
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help with your existing redirection rule, if you don't show it to us?

Comment: Could you please use the `edit` button below your question to add additional details and information? That way things stay readable... Thanks!

Comment: Also please explain what _exactly_ you mean by "does not work". What does that mean, actually? Does no rewriting occur? Is the rewriting wrong  somehow? Do you get an error? Or a blank page? Does the universe implode? You see we cannot look over your shoulder. You have to tell us...

Comment: It does not get redirected.

Comment: OK, thanks. The reason why this does not work is that you use that statement in a wrong way. This is not how it works. Please take a look into the documentation explaining the tools you use: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect If you really want to have exactly that redirection as you posted in your question, then you cannot use the `Redirect` command the Alias module offers. You must use the more complex combination of `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` implemented by the Redirect module.

Comment: Apart from that I think that you actually want the rule to work the other way 'round... So that the incoming request is `http://www.vbpmonitor.com/optimizing-vbm-quality-tiering-for-physicians`. so that must be matched by the pattern. But that is only a thought on my side, you may know better what you actually try to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning, but I have 40k emails that went out with that URL.  So I'm under the gun...

Comment: The form on that page does not function with the long url.  Only the SEF url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108671/discussion-between-modernmagic-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 1):

As said above in the comments I suspect that you have a glitch in your logic here and that in reality you want to redirection to work the other way 'round. Redirecting from the long to the search engine friendly URL simply does not make any sense. So:

Using a `Redirect` rule you could try that instead:

```
Redirect 301 /optimizing-vbm-quality-tiering-for-physicians /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=24&utm_source=MagnetMail&utm_medium=email&utm_term=asmith@panaceainc.com&utm_content=EVVWP040716&utm_campaign=White%20Paper%3A%20Optimizing%20VBM%20Quality%20Tiering%20for%20Physicians
```

This will redirect an incoming request to the short URL to the actually existing long URL. That is the usual scenario.

If however you *really* want to redirect that short URL to the long version, then you cannot do that with a `Redirect` rule. This might for example be the case if you accidentally sent out that long URL and have a working redirection setup for the short version. Unfortunately you do not explain anything about that in your question or comments, so I can only *guess* here.

You'd have to use the more flexible rewriting module and use a combination of `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. That allows to "cut out" specific patterns of request URLs and to "redesign" how the request should look like after the rewriting.

This would be a simple example that applies two conditions to rewriting the request for file `index.php` to the long URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=article 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=24
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /optimizing-vbm-quality-tiering-for-physicians [L,R=301]
```

*Note: this version should work both in the http servers host configuration and also in those `.htaccess` style files. Where you always should prefer the first option if you have access.*

As said above, I can only *guess* here with the sparse information you provided. I picked two out of many request arguments, since those appear to be the ones best suited as distinct identifiers. But you may have to tweak things. Note that per default `RewriteCond`s are combined by a logical `AND`, so they *both* have to resolve to something truish.

For more precise details about this stuff I would like to point you to the official documentation of those modules again. The documentation is extremely precise, well written and comes with good examples. I would always prefer the information there to snippets you find somewhere in the internet or partial answers to questions...

1. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect
2. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html